# ios - Can't upload a new Build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I'm having the same problem over and over again. I'm trying to upload a new build of an app, previously reviewed, and I'm always getting the same stacktrace (see below). Put a ticket to Apple, got ignored. Used their forums, got ignored.

It's a cordova project, so I build first via console, change version & build version, archive, and finally validate & upload.

I'm uploading using XCode 7 and Application Uploader (in order to use AU, I'm exporting from Xcode using the appstore export option first).

So far, I've tried to upload this combination of versions and build versions:

- v 1.5.0, bv 2.
- v 1.5.0, bv 1000.
- v 1.5.0, bv 1.5.1.
- v 1.5.0, bv 1.5.0.1.
- v 1.5.1, bv 1.5.1 (I changed iTunesConnect version too).
- v 2.0, bv 2.0 (I changed iTunesConnect version too).
- v 2.0.0, bv 2.0.0 (I changed iTunesConnect version too).

I tried changing the version on the app's code accordingly, too.

Ideally, it should be version 1.5.0, but I've reached a point where any version number would do.

This is the stacktrace:


    `[2016-09-07 09:36:12 BST]   INFO: Transporter is skipping bundle update check: Already checked recently.
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:679)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:415)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarContent.getEntryAsBytes(JarContent.java:135)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleImpl.java:1816)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:727)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.(MainClientExec.java:120)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:787)
        at com.apple.transporter.JSONService.(JSONService.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
        at com.apple.transporter.factory.WebServiceFactory.createWebService(WebServiceFactory.java:40)
        at com.apple.transporter.CommandLineOptionProcessor.parseMode(CommandLineOptionProcessor.java:318)
        at com.apple.transporter.CommandLineOptionProcessor.parse(CommandLineOptionProcessor.java:187)
        at com.apple.transporter.Application.processCommandLineArgs(Application.java:75)
        at com.apple.transporter.Application.begin(Application.java:95)
        at com.apple.transporter.osgi.TransporterService.run(TransporterService.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.runTransporter(OSGiBootstrapper.java:578)
        at com.apple.transporter.osgi.OSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(OSGiBootstrapper.java:304)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.apple.transporter.Application.start(Application.java:133)
        at com.apple.transporter.Application.main(Application.java:357)
    An error occurred while trying to start transporter. Exception's name: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, Exception's message: null`

```
ERROR: JarContent: Unable to read bytes. (java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuns out, after so many worries, the development machine I was logginng into had problems with the latest App Uploader. I changed to the previous App Uploader and it went smoothly.